# Python: calling a callback from within the user context

Tags: python, multithreading, sdk, callback, message-queue

I am developing an SDK for a device in Python. The SDK exposes various services from the device to a user application. The way the user can use these services is by providing the SDK with callback functions that the SDK calls whenever something happens.

Now the problem is that I need the SDK responses to be handled by the user application thread and not the SDK thread.

I already have the classic solution for this. The SDK places responses into the user thread's queue, and the user thread handles the responses in a loop. 
However, I am wondering if there is a way to simplify this for the user. With the current solution, the user needs to implement the queue and response handling mechanism himself. Is there any way to make this transparent to the user?

I am looking for a way for the SDK to call the user's callback functions but from within the user's thread.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The user thread has to cooperate in some way for this to happen. Lots of GUIs implement event loops where the user thread calls some `serve_forever` function in the SDK which handles the details of the queue and running the callbacks. This can get messy if the user is trying to integrate your SDK with another library that does event loops.

Comment: Do you have a link to an example that demonstrates this cleanly, preferably in Python?